# UIImagePicker: How to always pick square image from camera library?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, picker

I am wondering how I can always pick a square image from camera library using UIImagePicker?

So I have set `imagePicker.allowsEditing = true` and when the image I pick is large enough (larger than the square crop), the picked image is square. But, when the image that I pick is smaller, let's say it's 748 by 466, even though the square crop enclose the image including the top and bottom black parts, the picked image does not include the black parts and so it returns a non square image. How do I make it so that it always picks the black top and bottom parts so image is always square?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: I'd recommend adding the "black parts" after the image is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the method using CoreGraphics to add the black area manually, add them in the UIImagePicker delegate method:

```
let squareSideLength = image.size.width > image.size.height ? image.size.width : image.size.height
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(squareSideLength, squareSideLength), false, 1)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, squareSideLength, squareSideLength))
image.drawInRect(CGRectMake((squareSideLength - image.size.width) / 2, (squareSideLength - image.size.height) / 2, image.size.width, image.size.height))
let imageYouWant = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

use `imageYouWant` then.

Comment: Thanks for help Carrl, but I am uploading this picked image to my server, and to keep future renderings simple I want to upload only square images.. and if possible I want to keep the image as seen in the square crop (748 by 748) in my case. So right now im getting 748 by 466 image back and I don't want to make it 466 by 466, I need to get 748 by 748 even I have to include the black top and bottom...

Comment: This method adds black area after picking and image, right? This is not correct, because this black areas can overlap the image in places, where user don't need to do this. Also the result image would be with black areas, that looks not good. The better answer would be to use a custom library, where only square crop available.